# How to check and set all default types of an app in macOS?

Tags: macos, applications

I just switched from Windows to macOS. In Windows, I can use "Set defaults for applications" to select an app to see what file types or link types it can open, and change all default types for each app.

However, in macOS, I only found a way to change default apps by each type, which makes it difficult for me to control which types of files each app can open. Is there anything equivalent to the "Set defaults for applications" in macOS?

I've tried what's described in https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/choose-an-app-to-open-a-file-on-mac-mh35597/mac. But this is not what I expect. For each app, I expect a function to list and change all types it can open, just like Windows (ref: "How to set defaults for applications on Windows 11" section in https://www.ghacks.net/2021/10/27/how-to-change-default-programs-on-windows-11/):

[image]

Comment: "_For each app, I expect a function to list and change all types it can open, just like Windows_": macOS isn't Windows. You're going to have to learn some different paradigms and adjust your expectations.

Comment: @jsejcksn And many thanks for your recommendation of the related question! Although the RCDefaultApp mentioned in this question has not been updated since 2009, I've found SwiftDefaultApps, a modern alternative to RCDefaultApp, on Github (https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps). And it worked as expected despite some minor bugs on macOS 13.

Comment: You can quickly change the default for a single document or entire document type using "Get Info" [Cmd/i] on any file. You only really need SwiftDefaultApps if you're digging deeper. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4KHz.jpg You can also open with any appropriate app by right click, Open With > which is a one-off change & doesn't affect defaults. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HClAi.png